# LaTeX equation issue

Tags: math-mode, equations

This code line:

```
\[ f \ominus s2 \thickapprox (f \ominus s1) \ominus s1 \]
```

gives this error:

```
l.663 \[ f \ominus s2 \thickapprox
                                   (f \ominus s1) \ominus s1 \]
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: Have you added `\usepackage{amssymb}` in your document preamble?

Comment: Could you add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) to see the packages you use?

Comment: Search for `\thickapprox` in [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) and you'll see it forms part of the AMS package distribution...

Answer (score 1):

As Carla said: you have to load the package `amssymb`.

This MWE works:

```
\documentclass[openright,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[ f \ominus s2 \thickapprox (f \ominus s1) \ominus s1 \]
\end{document}
```

And its result:

[image]